# How can I test if a value is an instance of ObservableCollection<T>?

Tags: c#, generics

How can I test if a value is an instance of ObservableCollection? (and then operate on the collection, without using dynamic)

How can I remove the dynamic casts from this generic, Coming from Java, I would be able to use wildcard or raw generics in order to operate on the collections, without needing to know the types.

```
 object copiedValue = FetchCopyValue();
 if( copiedValue is ObservableCollection<Guid> 
  || copiedValue is ObservableCollection<AViewModel>
  || copiedValue is ObservableCollection<BViewModel>
  || copiedValue is ObservableCollection<CViewModel>
  || copiedValue is ObservableCollection<DViewModel>
 )
 {
     var sourceCollection = (dynamic) copiedValue;
     var destinationCollection = (dynamic) GetDestination(copiedValue);
     destinationCollection?.Clear();
     destinationCollection?.AddRange(sourceCollection);
 }
```

Where GetDestination returns an Observable Collection that is the same type as copiedValue

Comment: Is checking if it implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `ICollection` enough?

Comment: Probably, but it doesn't give the intention of the code.

Comment: That's true :-)

Comment: What is the signature of GetDestination?

Comment: I was hoping that `is` would accept an unbound generic type argument, i.e. `ObservableCollection<>`, but annoyingly this results in `Unexpected use of an unbound generic name`. I don't see any reason this wouldn't be allowed so I'm disappointed that it doesn't work.

Comment: What type is `copiedValue` when you get to the `if`? `Object`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could use method `IsGenericType` combined with `GetGenericTypeDefinition`:

```
var type = copiedValue.GetType();
if(type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ObservableCollection<>))
```

`type.IsGenericType` is used as a guard clause to prevent against exceptions in `GetGenericTypeDefinition` being thrown when called on non generic types.

This combined with Magnus's suggestion to cast it to `IList` should do the trick.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Because `IsGenericType` is a simple `bool` property and this check is almost instantaneous

Answer (score 2):

Since `ObservableCollection<T>` implements the non generic interface `IList` you can just cast to that. `IList` excepts `object` as parameter.
Example:

```
var copiedValue = new ObservableCollection<int>() {1,2,3};
var list = (IList)copiedValue;

list.Clear();
for (int i = 4; i < 8; i++)
    list.Add(i);
```

Comment: This along with the generic check to make sure I'm targeting the right thing could work.

Comment: If you only except a certain number of types than yes.

Answer (score 1):

Might be somewhat more maintainable as:

```
bool TryAddToDestination<T>(object o)
{
    if (o is ObservableCollection<T> sourceCollection)
    {
       var destinationCollection = GetDestination (sourceCollection);
       destinationCollection?.Clear();
       destinationCollection?.AddRange(sourceCollection);
       return true;
    }
    return false;   
}

void YourFunction()
{
    TryAddToDestination<Guid> || TryAddToDestination<AViewModel> || TryAddToDestination<BViewModel> || TryAddToDestination<CViewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created an extension method for such checks:

```
public static bool IsGenericTypeOf(this Type type, Type genericTypeDefinition)
{
    if (type == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
    if (genericTypeDefinition == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(genericTypeDefinition));
    return type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericTypeDefinition;
}
```

Usage:

```
if (copiedValue.IsGenericTypeOf(typeof(ObservableCollection<>)))
{
     // as the element type can be anything you cannot treat copiedValue as ObservableCollection here
     // But considering it implements nongeneric interfaces you can cast it to IList:
     IList sourceCollection = (IList)copiedValue;
     IList destinationCollection = GetDestination(copiedValue);
     destinationCollection.Clear();
     foreach (var item in sourceCollection)
         destinationCollection.Add(item);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just after you get to know the type cast it as matching type, like this:

```
if(copiedValue is ObservableCollection<Guid>)
{
     ObservableCollection<Guid> guids = (ObservableCollection<Guid>)copiedValue
     //now deal with guids
}
```

you may create a switch-case.

Comment: It doesn't answer the OP's question but that can now be written in C# 7 as  `if (copiedValue is ObservableCollection<Guid> guids) {   /* guids in scope here */ }`

Comment: Man I wish I could use 7.